# Outlook in O365 and calender sharing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, imap, calendar, office365

I have Office365 (just the software, no cloud service) and it was getting its mail and hooked up to an off site Exchange service. The service provider decided to shut down Exchange and move everything to POP/IMAP. The thing I am worried about is that we have a calendar in Outlook that we share amongst ourselves and will that sharing be broken once Exchange is out of the picture?

I am basically asking if the calendar is somehow dependent on Exchange or if it is just dependent on the applications on the local computers and the email addresses that are used in the sharing so switching to IMAP will not break the calendar sharing?

Comment: The calendar will not work on pop/imap. That’s disappointing. It’s a giant leap backwards and outlook was never designed to work as a pop/imap client. Office 365 hosted exchange is dirt cheap, my recommendation is that you move there. Otherwise you would do just as good to throw Outlook in the trash because most of the features you’ve come to appreciate will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find, the calendar sharing will no longer work or not work as it once did

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8/sharing-outlook-calendar-with-imap/2548b91a-506a-4961-bace-462a72f1ea6e

I would recommend you and the other people you share the calendar with migrate to a different service before they kill the exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

The calendar sharing feature requires Exchange accounts. Users can save the calendar locally to still access the copy of current appointments, however, without an Exchange server, the future changes made in the calendar will not sync to other users.

You may consider to publish an internet calendar and have all users subscribe to the internet calendar as a workaround. See:

[Introduction to publishing Internet Calendars](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-publishing-internet-calendars-a25e68d6-695a-41c6-a701-103d44ba151d)